# how to replace all instances of "[" and "]"

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this: [hello world] 
and i want to get hello world

having hard time finding the right regex for the replaceAll method for java

String s = s.replaceAll("[[]]",""); throws an exeption

what is the right regex for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` and and `]` are meta-characters used to define the bounds of a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html). They need to be escaped to be used within a regular expression themselves

```
s = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","");
```

Comment: Sorry for this, I tested this with RegexBuddy rather than Java source code, it seems that Java doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: I tracked this further and I was wrong, there is a simple mistake. You **must** escape the second `]` like this: `"[]\\[]"`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should try using `replace` instead:

`String s = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");`

Or it seems like you could just get away with using substring:

`String s = string.substring(1, string.length()-1);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
String s = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s =  "[hello world]";
        s= s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```